# Unknown Display Ubuntu 14.04 (Intel)

Tags: 14.04, display, intel-graphics, intel

I have an Intel G33 Chipset.

I can't seem to increase the resolution:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask; do you have a proprietary driver for this chip ? From terminal: `ubuntu-drivers devices`  ... (Never seen an "Unknown Display" tag before...)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can modify the resolution. You simply have to select the value that fits your screen from  drop-down list I surrounded in red here:

[image]